# Do getElementById for an HTML element inside a ExtJS panel

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I need to fetch an HTML element from an ExtJS panel and replace it with another HTML element.

I have a normal ExtJS panel -> rptPanel, whose innerHTML is copied to another panel -> outputDataPanel.

Please refer the code below.

```
    var html = rptPanel.body.dom.innerHTML;

    me.outputDataPanel.insert(me.itemIndex,{
        html    : html,
        border  : 0,
        cls     : 'htmlView_font_higher htmlView_font',
        style   : 'margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px; width: 100%;'
    });
```

Now, I need to fetch an HTML element inside `outputDataPanel` (something like `getElementById('table_data')` on `outputDataPanel` ) and replace it with another HTML element.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You'll need to post more information. A `document.getElementById` would be fine to access the DOM, which would probably mean you've got some other circumstance that won't allow that.

Comment: Since I am copying the innerHTML of rptPanel to outputDataPanel. Both the panels are having same HTML element (with their IDs). So if I do a getElementById, I am not sure which one will I get. Need to get and replace the one in outputDataPanel

Comment: how about `me.outputDataPanel.getElementById` - not sure if it will work as not sure what type of object `outputDataPanel`is

Comment: This will not work. Both rptPanel and outputDataPanel are ExtJS panels

Comment: Don't then. Ids should be unique on the page. If you're generating duplicate ids you're "doing it wrong".

Comment: OK. In that case, how can I fetch this component in outputDataPanel ?

Comment: `insert` returns the created component. This info is in the docs.

Comment: I am able to fetch the entire HTML inside the panel. But getting an HTML component from this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I suppose this is not Sencha's best practice):

```
outputDataPanel.getEl().down('#table_data')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set an ID to that element and get it like so:

```
// by id
var el = Ext.get("myDivId");
// by DOM element reference
var el = Ext.get(myDivElement);

// by id
var el = Ext.getDom('myDivId');
// by DOM element reference
var el = Ext.getDom(myDivElement);
```

Alternative way would be:

set an item-id to that element, lets say it's an item in the panel:

```
            {
                'text': 'myBTN',
                iconCls: 'sprite',
                disabled: true,
                itemId: 'btn1',
                handler: function(btn,e){
                    self.myFunction();
                }

            }
```

later on the code look for it by
this.down("#btn1")

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem even like a near solution to this issue. I need to get an html element from extjs panel. any ideas?

Comment: Why is the first solution isn't work for you? have you try this?
`var el = Ext.getDom('myDivId');`

This will return the html element from your extjs.